# Azure: WebRole OnStart() is never called

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I have a simple WebRole class in my Azure solution:

```
public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        DiagnosticMonitor.Start("DiagnosticsConnectionString");

        // For information on handling configuration changes
        // see the MSDN topic at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166357.
        RoleEnvironment.Changing += RoleEnvironmentChanging;

        CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher(
            (configName, configSettingPublisher) =>
            {
                string connectionString = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(configName);
                configSettingPublisher(connectionString);
            }
        );

        return base.OnStart();
    }
    // ...
}
```

For some reason, I can't get breakpoints in `OnStart()` to be hit when I run the project. Why might this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is that your startup project is your web application instead of the cloud project.  Make sure that the cloud project is the startup project, and then verify your app is running in the development fabric.

Comment: Ok, now this method is being called, but I can't get any breakpoints in my .svc file to be hit. I'm not sure that's at all related to changing the start up project.